# Java Spring Web Application - No mapping found for HTTP request

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, model-view-controller, fusioncharts

i spend a few hours fighting with my problem, but with no big result, maybe someone will help me :)

My project look like this:

[image]

I want to use a library to draw a chart from this tutorial:
[FusionCharts](https://www.fusioncharts.com/blog/spring-framework-charts/)

I got error message this:

> 09-Jan-2018 21:56:22.304 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound.noHandlerFound No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'
>   09-Jan-2018 21:56:22.323 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-3] org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound.noHandlerFound No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'
>   09-Jan-2018 21:56:22.465 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-5] org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound.noHandlerFound No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'

Files FusionCharts, fusioncharts.charts.js and fusioncharts.js are from library.

Home Controller Code:

```
package com.charts.controller;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.Controller;

public class HomeController implements Controller {
    @Override
    public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        return new ModelAndView("index");
    }

    public String chartmaker(){
        FusionCharts lineChart = new FusionCharts (
                "line",// chartType
                "chart1",// chartId
                "600","350",// chartWidth, chartHeight
                "chart",// chartContainer
                "jsonurl",// dataFormat
                "data.json"
        );
        return lineChart.render();
    }

}
```

index.jsp:

```
<%@ page import="com.charts.controller.HomeController" %>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="com.charts.controller.FusionCharts" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>FusionCharts || www.fusioncharts.com</title>
    <script src="../fusioncharts.js"></script>
    <script src="../fusioncharts.charts.js"></script>
    <script src="../fusioncharts.theme.fint.js"></script>
</head>
    <body>
    <div id="chart"></div>

    <%
        HomeController a = new HomeController();
        out.println(a.chartmaker());
    %>

    </body>
</html>
```

spring-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <bean id="HandlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping" />

    <bean id="/welcome.html" class="com.charts.controller.HomeController" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

</web-app>
```

When i run a project, i got this message:
[image]

When i go to the http://localhost:8080/welcome.html i got a clear screen and this library doesn't draw any chart or something like that.

My configuration files are properly like web.xml or spring-servlet.xml ? 
I will be grateful for any advices

Regards,
Adrian

Comment: You shouldn't instantiate and/or call methods on your Controller class from your JSP. Your Controller handler methods should return a view name which corresponds to a view (viewname.jsp). It might help to search for some Spring MVC tutorials and work through a getting started app first, as your current usage seems a bit confused.

Comment: You might also want to look at creating a new Spring MVC app with Spring Boot, as the configuration is vastly simplified (no need for xml config anymore)

Comment: In Controller i return a view index.jsp like that: @RequestMapping("/index")
    public ModelAndView hello() {
        return new ModelAndView("index");
    }, I did it a properly?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you annotate your `HomeController` class with `@Controller`, and inside a method with any name (ex. `public String showIndex() { return "index"; }` ). Annotate that method with `@GetMapping("/")` should work.

Answer (score 0):

we have a GreetingController that is mapped to /greeting and renders greeting.jsp:

```
@Controller
public class GreetingController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/greeting", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String get(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "Hello, World!");
        return "greeting";
    }
}
```

The corresponding view renders the value of the message variable:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Greeting</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>${message}</h2>
    </body>
</html>
```

Create a Java class that will act as the controller in the framework. The output of this will be an entire FusionCharts string you will call within the JSP page (or the view). The chart will render when you execute this string in the browser -

```
package fusioncharts;

/**
 *
 * @author fusioncharts
 */

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.Controller;

public class chartscontroller implements Controller{
    @Override
    public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        return new ModelAndView("/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp");
    }
    
     public String chartmaker(){
        FusionCharts lineChart= new FusionCharts(
            "line",// chartType
            "chart1",// chartId
            "600","350",// chartWidth, chartHeight
            "chart",// chartContainer
            "jsonurl",// dataFormat
            "data.json"    
            );
            
        
        return lineChart.render();
    }
    
}
```

Refer docs - https://www.fusioncharts.com/blog/spring-framework-charts/